# Firebase: Cloud Functions + Storage Read File

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am currently writing a function in Firebase Functions to be called within my Firebase mobile application. I have the code to call the function, but I do not know how to get this function to interact with Firebase storage.

I have a JSON file (300KB) of public non-sensitive information stored in a Firebase Storage bucket. Based on user input, I will select specific attributes of this JSON file and return the result to the user. However, I cannot figure out how to read this file from my Firebase Functions code. How do I do the following? Also, if anyone knows a more cost-effective way to do this, please let me know!!

```
exports.searchJSON = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const keyword = data.searchTerm
    //search the JSON file that is present in the storage bucket
    //save the sliced JSON object as a variable
    //return this to the user
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 options that you can use. See options below.

1. Firebase Admin

   ```
   const { initializeApp } = require('firebase-admin/app');
   const { getStorage } = require('firebase-admin/storage');

   initializeApp({
     storageBucket: '<BUCKET_NAME>.appspot.com'
   });

   const bucket = getStorage().bucket().file("<FILE-PATH>")
   .download(function (err, data) {
       if (!err) {
           var object = JSON.parse(data)
           console.log(object);
       }
   });
   ```

   Make sure you've installed the [Admin SDK module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-admin).

   ```
   npm i firebase-admin
   ```
2. Google Cloud Storage SDK

   ```
   const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

   const storage = new Storage();
   const fileBucket = '<BUCKET-NAME>.appspot.com';
   const filePath = '<FILE-PATH>';
   const bucket = storage.bucket(fileBucket);
   const file = bucket.file(filePath);

   file.download()
   .then((data) => {
   const object = JSON.parse(data);
   console.log(object);
   });
   ```

   Make sure you've installed the [`@google-cloud/storage`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/storage) module:

   ```
   npm i @google-cloud/storage
   ```

For more information, you may check out these documentations:

- [Introduction to the Admin Cloud Storage API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start)
- [Download an object from a bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#downloading-an-object)